# PDO json insert multiple tags

Tags: php, json, pdo

I've been trying to insert some tags into a table using pdo but to no avail.

I have a php array called Tag.

Sample data in tag array is as follows

```
   tag[] = [[a,b,c,d,e],[f,g,h,i,j]]
```

using a for loop below I'm able to convert it to (1,'a','b','c','e',0), (1,'f','g','h','i',0)

```
      $value="";
      $value .= "($postid,";
      for($i=0;$i<sizeof($tag);$i++)
      {
        $value .="'$tag[$i]'";
          if($i + 1 == $sizeof($tag){
          $value .=")";
         }else{
          $value .="),";
         }
      }
```

And prepare and insert into the table as follows

```
      $inserttagquery = "insert Into tagtable  ( postid, desc, b, u, toppos,leftpos ,ver) values :value";
      $queryinserttag = $conn->prepare($inserttagquery);
      $queryinserttag->execute(array('value'=>$value));
      $insertedtag = $queryinserttag->rowCount();
```

However, this does not seem to work. $insertedtag does not return any value.

Comment: [`PDOStatement->errorCode()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorcode.php)  ist there an output? 
Have you echo your query and check it for errors? Also `execute()` returns a boolean if the query was successful

Comment: Pro tip: `sizeof` is an alias real men use `count`.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is outright wrong. You're lising 6 fields **AND** a constant value in your field list, then providing only a SINGLE placeholder to provide values for those fields.

1. you cannot use numbers as a field name. `0` is a flat out syntax error and an invalid field name.
2. Placeholders have a 1:1 relation between a field and a value. You **CANNOT** shove multiple values into a single variable and try to use that value with a placeholder to fill in OTHER fields.

Your query should be:

```
INSERT INTO tagtable (postid, desc, b, u, etc...) 
VALUES (:postid, :desc, :b, :u, etc...)
```

and then you provide INDIVIDUAL values for each placehodler:

```
 $stmt->execute(array($postid, $desc, $b, $u, etc...));
```

As written, and ignoring all the other problems, your query would try shove your `(1, 'f', 'g', etc..)` string into JUST the `postid` field.

Comment: please see my edit. the problem with your answer is that it wouldn't work for multiple value. Thats is array index 0 through the end of the array

Comment: it would never work for multiple values. You cannot use mysql `insert into (...) values (...),(...),(...)` extended insert syntax with prepared statements, unless you put in a placeholder for **EVERY** value in the extended list - which then negates the point of preparing the statement. You need to prepare the statement ONCE, then execute it multiple times for each set of values.

Comment: Performance wise does is change anything. I'm moving form mysql_query to PDO and it seems i'm not able to do the things I did before